# ¿Cómo puedo solicitar la confirmación de cerrar la pestaña?

Tags: javascript

He visto que en páginas de publicidad se puede preguntar al usuario, cuando cierra la pestaña, si confirma el cierre de la pestaña o si desea seguir en la página. El mensaje es un alert con dos botones: `seguir aquí` y `salir`.
¿Cómo hago eso? Es que no lo encuentro.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

A mi me funciona con este código. Funciona tanto para cerrar la página como para cambiar hacia otra.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

window.onbeforeunload = preguntarAntesDeSalir;

function preguntarAntesDeSalir(){
return "¿Seguro que quieres salir?";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el evento `window.onbeforeunload` para detectar cuando se cierra la ventana

[jQuery & Javascript – Capture the Browser or Tab Closed Event](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/)

[Cómo detectar el cierre o la salida de una página Web](http://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/TRUCO-Como-detectar-el-cierre-o-la-salida-de-una-pagina-Web.aspx)

basicamente seria

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    window.onbeforeunload = function preguntarAntesDeSalir()
    {
        return "¿Seguro que quieres salir?";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La opción más fácil de confirmación es simplemente ingresar el método `confirm`. El cual muestra una caja de dialogo con un mensaje y dos botones: Aceptar y Cancelar. Si el usuario presiona Aceptar, el resultado es verdadero, de otra manera sería falso.

```js
var r = confirm("¡Presiona un botón!");
if (r == true) {
    alert("Presionaste aceptar");
} else {
    alert("Presionaste cancelar");
}
```

Por desgracia, no hay ningún soporte de navegadores (al menos que yo sepa) para la apertura de un diálogo de confirmación que no es la predeterminada de aceptar/cancelar. Las únicas maneras para poner otro texto en los botones sería utilizar un framework como [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) y su [dialogo de confirmación](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) o creandolo uno desde cero.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Borrar todo": function() {
          alert("Borraste todo");
        },
        "Cancelar": function() {
          alert("No se borro nada");
        }
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="¿Vaciar la papeleria de reciclaje?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Estos artículos serán borrados para siempre y no podrán ser recuperados. ¿Estás seguro?</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si me van a calificar negativo, estaría bien saber porque.