# ¿Como puedo eliminar la session al cerrar la pestaña?

Tags: php, html

compañeros. Trato de aumentar la seguridad en mi sitio, y he tratado de implementar la respuesta de este post:

> [¿Cómo puedo solicitar la confirmación de cerrar la pestaña?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20871/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-solicitar-la-confirmaci%c3%b3n-de-cerrar-la-pesta%c3%b1a)

al utilizar este codigo:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

window.onbeforeunload = preguntarAntesDeSalir;

function preguntarAntesDeSalir(){
return "¿Seguro que quieres salir?";
}

</script>
```

Pero no se como ponerle la instrucción o recuperar un dato que me permita evaluarlo para mandar la instrucción session_destroy() en php.

¿Me pueden ayudar en el código? o ¿pueden recomendarme una lectura o algun post? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un *confirm* y verificas si es true o no.

```
if(confirm('¿Seguro que quieres salir?')) {
// código que hacer si le da en sí.
}
```

Comment: Amigo. Por favor edita tu respuesta. Explica mejor el codigo y con mas detalles, de lo contrario sera eliminada.

Comment: es cierto jejejejej agradezco el apoyo pero es algo confusa la respuesta

Comment: creo que interpreté mal jajaj, (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103956/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-el-evento-del-cierre-de-tu-p%C3%A1gina-web) creo que a eso te refieres, no?

Comment: Si, algo así  @juan David casseres, pero ¿como hacer que el código PHP cierre la session, o en su defecto código Javascript que eliminé completamente la cookie usada para almacenar los datos de la session para que no sea abierta o analizada por alguna persona?